# How to prepare DB data before starting Espresso tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

DB : SQLite

Table : Contact

Espresso test:

```
@Test
public void testBlock() {
   onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.container_ListView)).atPosition(0).onChildView(withText(R.string.block_user))
            .perform(click());
}
```

And test success pass. But it succeeds only if before starting the contact has the status **unblock** (column **Status** in db table). So I need (before starting the test) to update this Contact to status **unblock**. How can I do this? Or has anyone a better solution for this?

Comment: how do you write to your database? do you have some sort of service class or helper?

Comment: I have service class that use  com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao to work with DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something you can either do it in a `@Before` method or within your testcase before starting the activity.

First you need to change your activity rule to this:

```
    @Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class, false, false);
```

Note the last `false` flag, this says that your activities are not launched automatically when your test start.

Then in your test class you could add this method:

```
 @Before    
 public static void PrepareDatabase() {
    // Instantiate your Service that performs an action on the database
    // give it this context: InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    // For example the code could look like this:
    DatabaseHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()).setYourValue();
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(null); //launches the test activity
}
```

Then normally write your test. This code performs some operation on your database and afterwards launches your activity for the test. You can also pass this into your test method instead of in the @Before method.

Comment: Would you happen to know where this DatabaseHelper class can be found? I can only access SQLiteOpenHelpen (its parent, as I was informed).

Comment: @TheFox the `DatabaseHelper()` is a helper class I wrote myself. It is just an abstraction to encapsulate the code which prepares the database. You could also simply put the database statements directly before the `mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);` line instead.